# Troubles with ROS Wiki Documentation

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I try to document my Stack on the Roswiki and indexed the stack as mentioned [here](http://wiki.ros.org/rosdistro/Tutorials/Indexing%20Your%20ROS%20Repository%20for%20Documentation%20Generation).
My rosinstall file for Fuerte looks like [this](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/doc/fuerte/bipedRobin.rosinstall).
I created a Wiki Page  [here](http://wiki.ros.org/bipedRobin)
and was now waiting for over an week and my Stack is still not indexed. What am I doing wrong?

Best Wishes

Johannes

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/88176/troubles-with-ros-wiki-documentation/) by [Johannes Mayr](https://answers.ros.org/users/4705/johannes-mayr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2013-10-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Johannes Mayr](https://answers.ros.org/users/4705/johannes-mayr/) on 2013-10-07**:
no ideas what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are getting a lot of warnings and errors due to undeclared dependencies.  The documentation will be built only with declared dependencies.  This is probably why the stack documentation is not being generated.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Johannes Mayr](https://answers.ros.org/users/4705/johannes-mayr/) on 2013-10-10**:
Thanks for the hint. I updated all manifest.xml files so that all dependancies are correct now. Let's see if this works out.

**Comment by [Johannes Mayr](https://answers.ros.org/users/4705/johannes-mayr/) on 2013-10-13**:
After updating all manifest.xml files I still get errors due to dependancies. The thing I do not understand is that dependancies to basic ros packages are missing:
"package/stack bipedRobin_local_planner depends on non-existent package tf".
Where else do I have to add this dependancies too?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can have a look at jenkins, the build/index server and see why [your job "doc-fuerte-bipedRobin"](http://jenkins.ros.org/job/doc-fuerte-bipedRobin/) failed. *I added a note for that to the tutorial.*

As a side note, the [ROS naming conventions](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Patterns/Conventions#Naming_ROS_Resources) advise to use lowercase underscored package names.

---

Originally posted by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) with karma: 1650 on 2013-10-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Johannes Mayr](https://answers.ros.org/users/4705/johannes-mayr/) on 2013-10-10**:
Thanks Felix!
I will rename my stacks an packages according to the naming conventions in the next day.
But still I don't now what the output of jenkins means. If I type rosmake in the stack directory everything workes fine with no errors. I guess there is something missing in my stack, but what?